# Get correct value from array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, kotlin

I have an array with the following values and a variable set to 0 that increases upon added bytes to the array:

```
data = [0, 0, 0]    
position = 0
```

I add a byte to the array:

```
data[position++] = 1
```

Which now is:

```
data = [1, 0, 0]
position = 1
```

My issue: Where 1 is in the array, the position of that byte is **0**, but my position is **1.** How can I set the position of that byte to **1**?

So I can get it like this:

```
data[position] <- Returns **1** -> data[1]
```

Now, when I use `data[position]`, it returns 0

Comment: When you do `position++` is increments after the scope block.  So, it would do `data[0] = 1` and then increment `position` after.  If you want it incremented before (which actually uses a tiny bit less memory) you would do `data[++position] = 1`

Comment: of course, because you incremented position... your intention is unclear

Comment: It is supposed to increment, because I am working with writing bytes. Write 1 byte increments the position that is being used to read. Thanks for that tip also!

Comment: FYI, Kotlin is not Java. You should pick the correct tag for the programming language you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `data[++position] = 1` instead of `data[position++] = 1`.

What's just happened?

If you use i++ (postfix) , `position` is increased by 1 but, the **old** value of `position` will be returned into the array index like `data[0]`.

If you use ++i (prefix) , `position` is increased by 1 and also the **new** value of `position` will be returned into the array index like `data[1]`.

In this case, using **prefix** firstly `position` increase by one and 1 will be assigned into  the first element of the array not zeroth element.

Answer (score 2):

By using the postfix increment the position is still 0 when its accessed in `data[position++]` and only after being accessed is the +1 value added. So you're basically doing `data[0] = 1`. Use `++position` so that position is incremented before its value is accessed.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your exact question, you could do this:

`data[position - 1]`

Comment:
But it's true that your question is not clear. When you say "a variable set to 0 that increases upon added bytes to the array", that means that when you add another byte to the array, like say

`data[2] = 0`

Now data == [1, 0, 1]. But position still equals 1. Who is responsible for incrementing `position`?

So what would you want to happen here?